# Can't Insert array data into QTableWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, desktop-application

I am making a desktop app for scientific purposes, and I am struggling to find info on the topic.

I have the code that scans the specific folder of excel files and saves its names and paths

```
sample_directory_2 = []
sample_files_2 = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Processed'):
    filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
    sample_files_2.extend(filenames)
    break
the_dir = "Processed"
paths_2 = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(the_dir,filename)) for filename in os.listdir(the_dir) if not filename.startswith('.')]    

sample_directory_2.append(sample_files_2)
sample_directory_2.append(paths_2)
```

Further, I have a piece of code, which gets the data from these files

```
processed_info = []
for i in range(len(sample_directory_2[0])):
    file_info = []
    sample_file_2 = sample_directory_2[0][i]
    sample_path_2 = sample_directory_2[1][i]            
    sample_info_2 = pd.read_excel(ospath(sample_path_2), header = None, sheetname = 3)
    sample_info_2 = sample_info_2.iloc[0][0:3]
    file_info.append(sample_file_2)
    sample_info_2_list = numpy.array(sample_info_2).tolist() 
    file_info.extend(sample_info_2_list)
    processed_info.append(file_info)
```

It is saved into an array

> [['sample1 (02:03:2018 14-38).xlsx', 3892.523626752876, 18.64406779661017, 0.6938147012986077],
>
> ['sample2 (02:03:2018 14-38).xlsx', 6135.581250460564,
>   79.66101694915254, 0.6072608909734578],
>
> ['sample3 (02:03:2018 14-38).xlsx', 3461.456815612303,
>   5.084745762711865, 0.676008795372024],
>
> ['sample4 (05:03:2018 07-28).xlsx', 6135.581250460564,
>   79.66101694915254, 0.6072608909734578]]

How to insert these pieces of data into QTableWidget cells, where each list (for example:['sample1 (02:03:2018 14-38).xlsx', 3892.523626752876, 18.64406779661017, 0.6938147012986077]) is inserted as a new row with 4 columns?

UPD: Found a way to add an item with

```
for row in range(len(processed_info)):
        for column in range(len(processed_info[row])):
            self.clickSample_list.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(processed_info[row][column]))
```

but, for some reason, it adds only first items of lists: [image: screenshot]

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem.

```
self.clickSample_list.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(processed_info[row][column]))
```

only works with string items, so I replaced it with

```
self.clickSample_list.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(processed_info[row][column])))
```

easy as it is